# Get name of attributes

Tags: python

I'd like to get the name of any attribute while iterating over it.

the ts3defines.py looks like [this](https://github.com/pathmann/pyTSon/blob/master/generated/pregen/ts3defines.py#L963):

```
class VirtualServerProperties(object):
    VIRTUALSERVER_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = 0
    VIRTUALSERVER_NAME = 1
    VIRTUALSERVER_WELCOMEMESSAGE = 2
    VIRTUALSERVER_PLATFORM = 3
    VIRTUALSERVER_VERSION = 4
    VIRTUALSERVER_MAXCLIENTS = 5
    VIRTUALSERVER_PASSWORD = 6
    VIRTUALSERVER_CLIENTS_ONLINE = 7
    VIRTUALSERVER_CHANNELS_ONLINE = 8
    VIRTUALSERVER_CREATED = 9
    VIRTUALSERVER_UPTIME = 10
    VIRTUALSERVER_CODEC_ENCRYPTION_MODE = 11
    VIRTUALSERVER_ENDMARKER = 12
```

the `getItems(object)` function looks like [this](https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/scripts/info/__init__.py#L13-L14):

```
def getItems(object):
    return [getattr(object, a) for a in dir(object)
                if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(object, a))]
```

the code in question looks like [this](https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/scripts/info/__init__.py#L140):

```
for var in getItems(ts3defines.VirtualServerProperties):
    (err, var) = ts3.getServerVariable(schid, var)
    if err == ts3defines.ERROR_ok and var != "" and var != 0:
        i.append('{0}: {1}'.format(var.__name__, var))
```

My question is about the `var.__name__` shouldn't that return the string `VIRTUALSERVER_BLA`, etc?

Why does it cause?

```
11/25/2017 16:07:44 pyTSon.PluginHost.infoData  Error   Error calling infoData of python plugin Extended Info: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blusc/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\pluginhost.py", line 476, in infoData
    data = p.infoData(schid, aid, atype)
  File "C:/Users/blusc/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\info\__init__.py", line 160, in infoData
    return self.getServerInfo(schid)
  File "C:/Users/blusc/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\info\__init__.py", line 148, in getServerInfo
    i.append('{0}: {1}'.format(var.__name__, var))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: What is the `var` value `ts3.getServerVariable(schid, var)` returns? In general Python objects don't have `__name__` attributes (`int`s for example), so why are you expecting one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you're trying to access `__name__`. You already have the name within the `getItems` method; it's `a`. You should return that and use it in the loop.

```
def getItems(object):
    return [(a, getattr(object, a)) for a in dir(object)
            if not a.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(object, a))]
```

...

```
for name, var in getItems(ts3defines.VirtualServerProperties):
    (err, var) = ts3.getServerVariable(schid, var)
    if err == ts3defines.ERROR_ok and var != "" and var != 0:
        i.append('{0}: {1}'.format(name, var))
```